# alert when focus is in text box only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, alert

I am getting an alert when i skip the text box but an alert is also coming wherever I click on page. How can I show an alert when the focus will be on the text box? The alert is also coming even when I open a new tab. Is there a way to solve this? Many thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $("input").blur(function() {
    if(!this.value) {
      alert("Text box " + ($(this).index() + 1) + " cannot be empty.");
      this.focus(); //Keep focus on this input
    }
});
```

body section

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox3"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox4"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  $(function() {
        $('input:text').blur(function() {
if(!this.value) {
    alert("Text box " + ($(this).index() + 1) + " cannot be empty.");
    this.focus(); //Keep focus on this input
}
});
});
```

also visit http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/

hope it helps.

Comment: sorry same problem occured again

Comment: replace $('input:text').blur(function()
with $('input[type=text]').blur(function()

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function getAlert(txt) {
                if (!txt.value) {
                    alert("Text box cannot be empty.");
                    txt.focus(); //Keep focus on this input
                }

        }; 
    </script>

<input type="text" id="textbox1" onfocus="getAlert(this)"/>
```

I hope that this resolved your problem.

Comment: It is only focusing on that text box only leads to total hanging of page

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(function() {
   $("input[type=text]").blur(function() {
       if (!this.value && $(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "text")
          alert("Text box " + ($(this).index() + 1) + " cannot be empty.");
          this.focus();
       }
    });
});
```

document.activeElement will get you current selected element and then you can compare if the selected element is a textbox.

hope this helps.........